# Can I send 1 on 1 email on Mailchimp API?

Tags: php, email, post, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to send a mail from email `FROM_EMAIL` to `TO_EMAIL` using PHP and Mailchimp API using just a POST request.

Mailchimp offers a marketing campaign API for sending emails in bulk from one sender to many recipients. However, I'm wondering if Mailchimp also provides an option for sending one-to-one emails from a sender to a specific receiver, like some other email API clients do. Am I just overlooking this option in Mailchimp?